# nginx uwsgi settings for app with different settingsnam

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I'm trying to setup a django app with nginx and uwsgi. The setup is such that there is one codebase but I run different instances, each pointing to a different database. Currently I have a uwsgi process defined for each application, but to me it seems like a waste since a lot of memory is taken up with the same code, while only the db connection strings are different.

I'm hoping have a setup where I am only creating one uwsgi process but pass a string into the uwsgi container which django can use to determine the database string and take it from there.

Initially I tried having a condition in the settings file such as this:

`settings.py`

```
import uwsgi
db_name = uwsgi.end['db_name']
```

I then passed the db name to the uwsgi instance. However only the first app's data is used. For example, if I restart the uwsgi server and first access `example1`, then `example2`, example1's database is used for both request. If I restart uwsgi again and access `example2` first, then that database is called, even if I access example1 afterwards.

I then changed tact and tried setting up dyamic apps. I copied the codebase to two different locations with only the settings file being different. However, the same thing happens as above.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Is there a way for the settings to (re)load on each request?

**update**:

After much trying, I still haven't got it right. I followed the advice given, but no luck. Here's mu current setup

`uwsgi.ini`

```
[uwsgi]
master = true
single-interpreter = true
processes = 1
threads = 0
socket = /var/run/uwsgi/lms_gui.sock
logto = /tmp/lms_gui.log
uid = nginx
reload-os-env = true

virtualenv = /var/www/myenv
plugins = python27
chdir = /var/www/squire/sites/lms/gui
```

`nginx`

```
server {
listen 162.13.123.195;
server_name example1;

location / {
    uwsgi_pass unix:///var/run/uwsgi/lms_gui.sock;
    uwsgi_param site_name example1;
    uwsgi_param UWSGI_MODULE example1_wsgi;
    uwsgi_param UWSGI_SETENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=example1_settings;
    include uwsgi_params;
}
}
server {
listen 162.13.123.195;
server_name example2;

location / {
    uwsgi_pass unix:///var/run/uwsgi/lms_gui.sock;
    uwsgi_param site_name example2;
    uwsgi_param UWSGI_MODULE example2_wsgi;
    uwsgi_param UWSGI_SETENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=example2_settings;
    include uwsgi_params;
}
}
```

As initially, the setups only load the settings file on the first request, but never again. I've also changed the names of the wsgi.py entry points, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible to have such a setup (and it was pretty common some years ago under uWSGI) it causes (soon or later) headaches all over the place.

The best (or better: saner) approach is starting a single process for each uWSGI instance and let it scale to more workers when needed:

--processes 8 --cheaper 1 --idle 60

will start each instance with only one worker, and eventually (as needed) will raise up to 8. In addition to this when the instance is idle for more than 60 seconds it will be put on hold (only the master running) until another request is issued.

There are other fine-tuning you can make, but the general rule is that multiple interpreters under django (for the way it works) are not an easy path to follow.

Comment: The problem is I have to run 1 worker per site. So assuming I have 10 sites (same codebase, but 10 different dbs since dbs are isolated), I have 10 processes with much the same memory footprint. I was hoping to reduce the memory footprint and save on server resources

Comment: you can gain no more than a couple of megs per-app using multiple python interpreters. and that memory (that is the uwsgi-only memory) can be reduced/shared using KSM under linux. By the way, if you want to try check here: http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/TipsAndTricks there is an example using --reload-os-env and UWSGI_SETENV var (that is the trick for django)

Comment: Thanks for your help and tips. I still haven't got it right. The settings still don't load every request. I've posted some code. I'd appreciate it if you could take one last look. after this i'll call it a day and run a uwsgi instance per application

Comment: single-interpreter is wrong as you definitely need multiple interpreters, then you need some form of "key" to instruct uWSGI wich apps to route requests to, add vhost = true and vhost-host = true to use HTTP_HOST as the key.

Comment: ok, I'll go back to multiple-interpreters. Thanks for all your help

Comment: Ah, ok, i get it. I removed single-interpreter (I thought that had something to do with threads). I also used vhost. Its working now